# Data type check results in a never ending loop in C

Tags: c, types, io

I am checking the return value from scanf to see if the type entered by the user is right, and it works when the code is right, but when I ender a char or something other than a double the program loops infinetely. I am just doing a basic check, I know that this won't catch cases where the user inputs "23w4", it'll just parse 24, I just want to catch cases where the user enters "zero" or some other non-double into the program. Below is the piece of code:

```
double getDeposit() {
int noError = 0;
double Deposit = 0;
while(noError == 0) {
    int errorCheck = scanf("%lf", &yearlyDeposit);
    if(errorCheck == 0) {
        printf("Invalid input, please try again");
    } else {
        noError = 1;
    }
}
return yearlyDeposit;

}
```

Comment: What is the type of yearlyDeposit? double?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very common problem: when `scanf` returns zero, it does not make any progress reading the data in the buffer. Whatever was entered remains buffered, so the next invocation of `scanf` can read it.

To fix this, add a read of data up to the new line, and discard whatever is entered, like this:

```
if(errorCheck == 0) {
    printf("Invalid input, please try again\n");
    scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");
} else {
    ...
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/y0OrEr)

Comment: Would you be able to explain that regular expression for me?

Comment: @MiguelJ. This is not quite a regular expression, although it certainly looks like one. The `[^\n]` part means "read everything except `'\n'`. The `\n` at the end means "consume trailing whitespace". The %* part means "throw away whatever you read next". (thanks, BLUEPIXY, for the correction)

Comment: "The \n at the end" : perhaps, It is not  well because it causes the input wait. Also not necessary it from being consumed in the next `"%lf"`. I think appropriate use `%*c` If it is desired to consume the newline in this point.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Well, `"%*c"` would let OP read `xyz1.23` as valid input,which may or may not be what he wants to happen.

Comment: I say `"%*[^\n]%*c"` instead of `"%*[^\n]\n"`